# Upgrade nano on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, install

I have followed the suggestion in this answer [How do you update the default version of Nano on MacOS without using the homebrew package manager?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366966/how-do-you-update-the-default-version-of-nano-on-macos-x-without-using-the-homeb/390251#390251)

I have macOS High Sierra.
After the installation I have tried:

```
$ nano -V
```

And the output is:

```
GNU nano version 2.0.6 (compiled 19:06:01, Oct  6 2017)
 Email: nano@nano-editor.org    Web: http://www.nano-editor.org/
 Compiled options: --disable-nls --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8
```

So I have tried to see where nano is located:

```
$ which nano
```

and the output is

```
/usr/local/bin/nano
```

Checking the path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I don't understand, if the first path is where nano is installed, why the new version is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running a binary from your shell, the shell stores its path within `PATH` in a cache and uses that value for future calls to avoid having to research the path each time. If you then install a new version of this binary in a different location the shell won't notice this and keep running the previous version.

**If you are running `bash`**

- `hash -t nano` will show the currently used version of `nano` (if any)
- `hash nano` will update the cache for `nano`

**If you are running `zsh`**

- `hash -m nano` will show the currently used version of `nano` (if any)
- `hash -f nano` will update the cache for `nano`

Answer (score 0):

After making a change to the shell like editing `PATH`, reload it as follows:

**Bash**: `exec bash`

**Zsh**: `exec zsh`

(For me `hash nano` didn't do anything and `-t` results in `bad option: -t`.)

Comment: `-t` only works in `bash`, the options are different in `zsh`.

Comment: Editing `PATH` variable would cause the hash table to be thrown out. An old trick is to reassign `PATH`-  `PATH=$PATH` to clear the hash table.