# nano only opens the first file given on the command line

Tags: command-line, text-editor, setup

Setting up a new MacBook. I like to use `pico`, so I always remember to add

```
export EDITOR=nano
alias pico=nano
alias pcio=nano
alias pioc=nano
```

to my `.profile`. But I'm still missing *something* that I used to have, because whenever I launch `nano` with multiple command-line arguments, instead of opening each file in sequence, it only opens the first filename.

```
nano x.txt y.txt # edits x.txt and then quits!
```

This isn't how it behaved on my old machine. What's the fix? (Is there an environment variable to make `nano` open multiple files?)

Answer (score 1):

macOS nowadays ships with a *very* old version of `pico`, instead of `nano`, by default. (`pico` doesn't even recognize the standard `-v` or `--version` arguments; it treats them as filenames.)

```
$ which nano
/usr/bin/nano
$ /usr/bin/nano -version
Pico 5.09
$ man /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1
[...]
Syntax
       pico [ options ] [ file ]
[...]
```

The solution is simply to install a (much) newer version of `nano`. The easiest way is `brew install nano`. Or without Homebrew, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366966/how-do-you-update-the-default-version-of-nano-on-macos-x-without-using-the-homeb). After `brew install nano`, I see:

```
$ which nano
/opt/homebrew/bin/nano
$ nano --version
 GNU nano, version 7.2
 (C) 2023 the Free Software Foundation and various contributors
 Compiled options: --disable-libmagic --enable-utf8
$ man nano
[...]
SYNOPSIS
       nano [options] [[+line[,column]] file]...

       nano [options] [[+[crCR](/|?)string] file]...
[...]
```

which indicates (truthfully) that `nano` 7.2 supports multiple filenames on the command line. That's all it took!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152019/discussion-on-answer-by-quuxplusone-nano-only-opens-the-first-file-given-on-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.